# Fluent Nhibernate many-to-many where table has multiple columns

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to to map a many to many relationship using Fluent NHibernate.

I have a table User and a second table Organization. The association table is UserOrganization which contains the UserId and OrganizationId. The UserOrganization table also contains a few other fields (YearBegan, YearEnd).

How would I go ahead and map those using fluent mapping.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably make UserOrganization its own entity that contains those fields.  That also gives you more flexibility in terms of cascading updates and deletes.

```
public class UserOrganization {
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime YearBegan { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime YearEnd { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nick, how would you go about adding a new user to an existing organization. Would you generate a UserOrganization object and assign the new User and the existing organization to it then use a UserOrganizationRepository to commit everything?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. You could dress up your User domain model a bit too with an AddOrganization(Organization org, DateTime yearBegan, DateTime yearEnd) method which creates the UserOrganization object, sets the properties and adds to the User.Organizations collection.  Makes it more straight forward as to how to consume the domain model.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I posted a follow-up question. If you have a second I would love your input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452722/fluent-nhibernate-many-to-many-issue